# Timeout configurations in Curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I create a Curator client as follows:

```
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryNTimes(3, 1000);
    CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnectString, 
            15000, // sessionTimeoutMs
            15000, // connectionTimeoutMs
            retryPolicy);
```

When running my client program I simulate a network partition by bringing down the NIC that Curator is using to communicate with Zookeeper.  I have a few questions based on the behavior that I am seeing:

1. I see a `ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED` message after 10 seconds.  Is the amount of time until Curator enters the SUSPENDED state configurable, based on a percentage of the other timeout values, or always 10 seconds?
2. I do not receive **any** notification after the configured 15-second session timeout has passed since the last successful heartbeat.  I **do** see a `ZooKeeper - Session: 0x14adf3f01ef0001 closed` message in the log, however this does not appear to trickle up as an event that I can capture or listen on.  Am I missing something here?
3. I eventually receive a `ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST` message almost two minutes after the connection loss.  Why so long?
4. If my goal is to use an InterProcessMutex as a means of preventing split-brain in an HA scenario, it seems that the safest approach is for the lock holder to assume that it has lost the lock when the `SUSPENDED` message is received, since it is entirely possible that Zookeeper has released the lock
   unbeknownst to it on the other side of the network partition.  Is this a typical/sane approach?

Comment: did you find an answer to your questions? I'm experiencing the same issues.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the PathChildrenCache (Deprecated now on 5.2.1, I don't know about earlier version), will still fire the node addition/deletion events after being disconnected for brief amounts of time, which is very helpful. But after the re-connection, it won't detect the deletion or addition of nodes that wasn't cached by the PathChildrenCache before the disconnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Assume leadership has been lost on SUSPEND and LOST. 
This is the way the Apache Curator recipes work.
You may want to use Apache Curator rather than implementing your own algorithm. 
https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends which version of Curator you're using (note: I'm the main author of Curator)...

In Curator 2.x, the LOST state means that a retry policy has been exhausted. It does not mean that the Session has been lost. In ZooKeeper the session is only determined to be lost once the connection to the ensemble is repaired. So, you get SUSPENDED when Curator sees the first "Disconnected" message. Then, when an operation fails due to the retry policy giving up you get LOST.

In Curator 3.x the meaning of LOST was changed. In 3.x when the "Disconnected" is received Curator starts an internal timer. When the timer passes the negotiated session timeout Curator calls getTestable().injectSessionExpiration() and posts a LOST state change.

Comment: What about the first question? Would you please comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

The first question, Zookeeper has a variable called MAX_SEND_PING_INTERVAL which is 10 seconds, so It's always 10 seconds on your condition.The code is in the ClientCnxn class.

```
//1000(1 second) is to prevent race condition missing to send the second ping
//also make sure not to send too many pings when readTimeout is small 
int timeToNextPing = readTimeout / 2 - clientCnxnSocket.getIdleSend() - 
        ((clientCnxnSocket.getIdleSend() > 1000) ? 1000 : 0);
//send a ping request either time is due or no packet sent out within MAX_SEND_PING_INTERVAL
if (timeToNextPing <= 0 || clientCnxnSocket.getIdleSend() > MAX_SEND_PING_INTERVAL) {
    sendPing();
    clientCnxnSocket.updateLastSend();
} else {
    if (timeToNextPing < to) {
        to = timeToNextPing;
    }
}
```